# Going to Germany to work, but I won't be an employee

Tags: visas, germany

I'm a PhD student, and I was invited for a month to Germany for research work at an institute. The invitation letter says explicitly that I won't be an employee, but I will receive a grant.

As a holder of Moldovan nationality, I can travel to Germany up to 3 months with the tourist visa. What bothers me is that I won't be a tourist, strictly speaking, and for the work I need to apply for the national visa. On the other hand, I won't be an employee, so I'm not sure if they can give me a national visa based on the work permit.

I know that in practice I just enter the country without even officials asking me the purpose of entry. But it still bothers me.

Am I breaking the law if I'm implicitly claiming that I'm a tourist, but in practice I do research?

P.S. The invitation letter also says that my name and affiliation will be added to the public guest list. I guess, the "guest" word might suggest that my visit can be regarded as of a touristic nature. It's just that a tourism has never been associated with a research at an institute in my mind.

Comment: Have you asked the institute about that?

Comment: Note that visa-free entry is not restricted to just “tourism”, it also includes “business”. No idea if your activities qualify for “business” though. Also there may be specific visas for academic work.

Comment: If you're staying for less than 90 days, you're falling under Schengen short-stay rules. National visas only apply for stays longer than 90 days so you don't need to worry about that. As a Moldovan citizen, you do not need a visa for a short stay (if you have a biometric passport) so you would not be entering on “tourist visa”, you are simply exempted from the visa requirement. This covers any purpose, not only tourism or even business.

Comment: That said, if what you are going to Germany to work, you may need some sort of permit or authorisation. The only question left (to which I don't have an answer) is whether this invitation letter is enough or if you need to secure some sort of additional document or permit.

Comment: @jcaron That's not exactly how it works. Schengen short-stay visas cover any purpose and the visa code does not foresee any other visa for academic or any other purpose beside airport transit. Schengen visas are certainly not limited to any sort of restrictively defined “business”; things like “medical reasons” or “study” are even mentioned explicitly in the application form annexed to the Visa Code with “business” merely 1 of 10 potential purposes, including ”other”. If specific prior authorisation is required (e.g. for work) then it must be secured *before* applying for the visa.

Comment: You travel only for a short time, but the employment angle makes this better suited to Expatriates Stack Exchange.